# Search for a text from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, full-text-search

I am a newbie to javascript and trying to search for text in an external html page. 
I am trying to achieve this directly on the browser and hence nodejs is not an option.

I know this is not the very kind of question asked on SE but I am left with no option.
So far even an extensive search on internet didn't solve my problem.
Any pointer could be helpful.

Comment: `external html page` If from different domain, this has to be proxified server side.

Comment: What do you want to do with the text? Do you want to search for the first appearance?

Comment: @user3790680 I have a string which is part of a content in the html page. I just have to search this string and extract the entire content in that external page.

Comment: @A.Wolff It is definitely on a different domain :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do it in client, it's typical job on server side. Browser will block such script for security reason.

Comment: What the @codejammer asks can be done. No problem, only since he/she isn't that experienced, maybe it is better to follow an easier path, like using php for example instead of JS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, you should be using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Include this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

PHP

```
//find.php

    <?php
    $url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    $strtofind = $_REQUEST['strtofind'];
    $cont = file_get_html($url)->plaintext; 
    $pos = strpos($cont , $strtofind );
    echo ($pos==false?"Not found":"Found");
?>
```

Here is JS Function

```
//js function
$.get("find.php?url="+url+"&strtofind="+strtofind, function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

Pass whatever URL you want to paas. The JS will make a request and the PHP file will give the source code.